# Zk-Snarks library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, blockchain

I am experimenting with ZK-SNARKS and wanted to know if there was any library I can use in JavaScript.
So far I have found out (https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs) but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and got `snarks.js` to work.

You need to use the following

```
const {stringifyBigInts, unstringifyBigInts} = require("./node_modules/snarkjs/src/stringifybigint.js");
```